# Convert String date into date in jsp using jstl

Tags: java, jsp, timezone, jstl

How I can convert my string date "2020-07-05 04:02:11 AM MST" into the date in JSP using JSTL.
I want to convert the whole date like with timezone.
when I am trying to convert it, it gives me date 07/05/20 11:02 AM GMT but in my string, the time zone is 'MST'.

```
<c:set var="timeZone" value="${fn:substring(txHistoryData.strTxTimeStamp, 24, 26)}" />
<fmt:parseDate value="${historyData.strTxTimeStamp}" var="txDt" timeZone="${timeZone }" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a z" />
```

and I am displaying it using following code:

```
<span class="data-label--top"> 
  <fmt:formatDate value="${txDt}" pattern="MM/dd/yy" /> 
</span> 
<span class="data-label--bottom"> 
  <fmt:formatDate value="${txDt}" timeZone="${timeZone}" pattern="hh:mm aa z" />
</span>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried capital Z instead of z? If not, try that and share the outcome.

Comment: Try removing `timeZone="${timeZone}"` and see what happens. I would have thought you wouldn't need it as the timezone is within your date string already.